# Default values of friction in urdf

Tags: drake

I have modeled a multibody plant with a ball moving over a plane. I have not included any collision tags with friction values myself, so I originally assumed it would be frictionless. However, it seems that the force and velocities do not agree if it were actually a frictionless surface. How can I find what the default values of friction are?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that these are difficult to find in the documentation. Searching the code, I see that the default values are `CoulombFriction<double>(1.0, 1.0)`, which are specified [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b081fce2af3871b5c2e8cc9c860774435bf41cf1/multibody/parsing/detail_common.h#L88).

You can also recover those values for yourself using (the unfortunately verbose):

```
from pydrake.all import RobotDiagramBuilder

xml = """
<mujoco model="test">
<worldbody>
    <geom name="floor" type="box" size="5 5 5" pos="0 0 -5" />
    <body name="ball">
    <joint type="slide" name="z" axis="0 0 1" />
    <geom name="ball" type="sphere" size="1" mass="1" />
    </body>
</worldbody>
</mujoco>"""

# Note: The RobotDiagram is just a quick way to build the plant + scene graph.
builder = RobotDiagramBuilder()
builder.parser().AddModelsFromString(xml, "xml")
diagram = builder.Build()

inspector = diagram.scene_graph().model_inspector()
contacts = inspector.GetCollisionCandidates()
friction = inspector.GetProximityProperties(contacts.pop()[0]).GetProperty(
    "material", "coulomb_friction"
)
print(f"static_friction = {friction.static_friction()}")
print(f"dynamic_friction = {friction.dynamic_friction()}")
```

which prints

```
static_friction = 1.0
dynamic_friction = 1.0
```

There is relatively [extensive documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__contact__engineering.html) of how the contact is implemented given those values.